# How do I setup Symantec Endpoint Protection Server to work on a standalone network?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, anti-virus, symantec-endpoint-protection

I have Symantec Endpoint Protection (ver 11) on a standalone network that will not have access to the internet. I need to burn updates on CDRs and move them to this network.

I need to know:

- Where do I download the latest updates
- How exactly do I import these updates
- How do I configure the server to use them

Comment: Not to be sarcastic but the SEP documentation covers everything you need to know about installing and configuring SEP.

Comment: How about a link to the documentation? I'm offsite and have limited access to the internet, so anything is appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=DOC2349&key=54619&actp=LIST

http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=DOC2350&key=54619&actp=LIST